# HTML URL Naming Convention

Tags: html

I'm crafting a generic html form with an input field that allows the user to enter the first part of a URL, that will then automatically be concatenated w/ a variable when displayed on a web page.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="link" value="https://www.example.com/en-US/search?q=">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The html for the link appearing on the web page is:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/en-US/search?q=XYZ">Click Here</a>
```

In this context: Is there a short, formal or common name used to refer to the part of the URL before the XYZ? I'm referring to: "https://www.example.com/en-US/search?q=". Thanks.

Comment: If you need parsing you can safely assume that you get the string by combining `origin + path + (query split by "=" taking the first element) + =` Note that sometimes different names are used for the different parts. E.g. "origin" is `scheme + authority`, "path" may be "pathname" or "query" might be called "search".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no commonly used name for that.

From [RFC 3986 Section 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3), here are the parts of the URI:

```
  foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
  \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
   |           |            |            |        |
scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
   |   _____________________|__
  / \ /                        \
  urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
```